# How to design an interface that accepts a config to override default settings?

Tags: c#, interface

Say I have a C# interface such as:

```
public interface IDatabaseRepository {

    void Load<T>(IEnumerable<T> data);

}
```

Now I have a concrete class as:

```
public class SQLRepository {
    
    private string _tableName;

    public SQLRepository(string tableName) {
        _tableName = tableName;
    }

    public void Load<T>(IEnumerable<T> data) { }

}
```

Imagine I want to support e.g., a different table name than what was provided in the constructor.
Or support e.g., some sort of config data structure that can override default settings.

How would I go about doing that?

Can it be designed without exposing implementation details of the interface?

Comment: Is you wnat SQLRepository that do not public Load<T> this method?

Comment: My understanding of dependency inversion and interfaces is to create a contract where any implementation-specific settings are provided at construction.  What if I want to change those settings mid-use?  In the example above, that would be table name.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean , you just cast SQLRepository to IDatabaseRepository ,for other class just use that , why you care about specific setting.